# how to install calabash for android in windows 8?

Tags: java, android, windows, calabash

does anyone know how to install calabash for android in windows 8?

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOW TO INSTALL CALABASH FOR ANDROID IN WINDOWS

Steps to follow:

1. Download Ruby.exe with version less than 2.0 (In this tutorial I am going to use rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p545.exe) from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Install the Ruby Software and by ticking the check boxes, Ruby will be settled on Environment Variables
Next Add in System Varibles

Variable Name: ANDROID_HOME
Variable Value: C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk

Variable Name: JAVA_HOME
Variable Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\

Variable Name: JRE_HOME
Variable Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\

Variable Name: Path
Variable Value: *;C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools;C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools

2. Download Ruby Development Kit (For use with Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3)
3. Create a folder called DevKit in  C:\DevKit
4. Extract Ruby Development Kit (DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe) to C:\DevKit
5. Open command.exe or cmd.exe and type ruby -v to check ruby version(ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32])
6. Now type: cd C:\DevKit and press enter
7. Then type: ruby dk.rb init
8. Then type: ruby dk.rb install
9. Then change to Ruby193 directory by typing: cd C:\Ruby193 on cmd
10. Type: gem install calabash-android
11. Type: gem install calabash-cucumber
12. check by typing: calabash-android version
13. In order to test you *.apk file in calabash you need to re-sign it
    So to make it work you can use two options

Option 1: 
Type: calabash-android resign *.apk and press enter
Type: calabash-android build *.apk and press enter

or

Option 2:
Use a .jar file called re-sign.jar

14. Then create a folder called sample in your desktop and place *_debug.apk. Open cmd then change directory where the *_debug.apk file is found and type: calabash-android gen , to generate the feature files and other associated resources.
15. Last you need to type: calabash-android run *_debug.apk to run the application

Note: To run the application you can use emulator, android device, android screen cast or any related software or devices that allows you to view the process.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Use this link  :http://rubyinstaller.org/

Step 2 :-Android SDK :
          Download & install SDK

Step 3:-Install android libraries
Launch installed sdk and choose one of the latest android api to install 
(if you know minSdkVersion for you app install that also)

Step 4 :-
Set environment variable for calabash
(Follow this link:-http://www.mobiletestworld.com/2014/02/steps-to-set-enviroment-variables-for.html)

Step 5:-Then connect your device 
Relaunch terminal and run these commands

~ $: adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
479005cda7cxxx device

windows: if devices are not listed its mostly problem with drivers
 ( install HTC sync for HTC devices / samsung kies for samsung devices)